# React Native Android is suddenly unable to find google services

Tags: android, gradle, react-native, google-play-services

Yesterday I was happily compiling my app on both iOS and Android. When I came back nothing worked anymore on Android.

> google-services plugin could not detect any version for com.google.android.gms or com.google.firebase, default version: 9.0.0 will be used.
>   please apply google-services plugin at the bottom of the build file.

The message is pretty straightforward and I already had to deal with it a couple of times already when installing dependencies into the app. And I always managed to solve this problem. But this time it is showing for absolutely no obvious reason as I didn't touch my android sdk.

Futhermore, my gradle config file has not been touched neither. And below you will see I also have the `apply google-services plugin` line at the end of the file.

I tried coming back to an older commit, just in case. But things remain the same and I'm a little overwhelmed by the problem right now..

Here is my `app/gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myApp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
            storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.1'
        force "com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1"
        force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.1"
        force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.1"
        force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.1"
        force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.2.1"
        force "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1"
        force "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.2.1"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-maps')
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile project(':react-native-firebase-analytics')
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
  from configurations.compile
  into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And here is a screenshot of my android SDK Manager

[image: SDK Manager screenshot]

Does anyone have an idea of what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem. Actually I don't know why it was working before at all.

But, by reading my code I actually saw that I `force` a version of Firebase but I never actually compile it... So I removed the `force` from the `configuration` and moved my dependence in the `dependencies block`

I really don't know if this is the right solution
But this fixed my problem:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.1'
        force "com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1"
        force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.2.1"
        force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.1"
        force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.1"
        force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.2.1"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-maps')
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile project(':react-native-firebase-analytics')
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.1"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.2.1"
}
```